# Get object keys as string, without loops or index

Tags: javascript

I have next object:

```
const obj = {
  size: 2,
  length: 34,
  status: 0,
}
```

I need to get keys of objects as string: `obj.size -> 'size'`, without using loops.

Comment: It is impossible. Any method will necessarily involve looping over the properties of the object *somehow*

Comment: Why can't you use loops or an index?

Answer (score -3):

```js
var obj = {
  size: 2,
  length: 34,
  status: 0,
};

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj)
);
```